# Is there a build system does not use timestamp to check file change

Tags: build, makefile

Build systems like make use timestamp check if a dependency is changed during two build. Here are a few common issue I run into with timestamp

- Open a file, make some change, but later, I decided it is not good. I revert the change, for example, `git checkout -- file` if I am using git for the project.
- Open a file, I just accidentally hit keyboard shortcut for save of the editor

Either way, the file's timestamp is changed. If now I want to build the project, everything depending on that file need to be rebuilt. This often means the whole project.

Is there anyway around these issues? For example, a build system using a version control for checking file change, preferably git. Or any other solutions to the above issues are welcome.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[SCons](http://scons.org/) uses [checksums, not timestamps](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/ch06.html) by default. However, checksumming requires reading all the contents of all the source files on disk, and that is much slower than simply reading directory entries, which is why most build systems use timestamps.

[Software Build Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321717287) gives a good overview of these issues.

Comment: The "checksums" link is dead.

Comment: @krlmlr Fixed. I used web.archive.org to view an old version of the page, used that to google for a more recent link, and edited the answer. You can do the same with dead links you come across on this site.